# Run a specific sudo command without a password in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: command-line, 13.10, sudo, vagrant, visudo

I would like to run *vagrant* without being prompted for a password. As this post suggests, I used *visudo* to add the following line to my *sudoers* file.

```
john-moz ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vagrant
```

This does not seem to work. I am still prompted for a password when using *vagrant*. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
john-moz host = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vagrant
```

You must change host to your hostname (probably also john-moz)

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. I notice that the `vagrant` script in turns starts up some other scripts. Perhaps the setting does not trickle down to them.

Answer (score 1):

Check where `vagrant` actually is: `which vagrant`. Maybe you have it installed as a gem (which is now obsolete way to install Vagrant).

But you really should never run Vagrant as a root. Why would you need to?

Comment: I installed Vagrant from a .deb that was downloaded on vagrantup.com. I'm not running Vagrant as root, but Vagrant does need my password to write to /etc/exports.

Comment: Aah, now I understand your issue. I'll write a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Vagrant itself* runs many `sudo` commands to modify /etc/exports and restart the NFS server. You rule doesn't match any of those.

The used commands vary between host OSs and Vagrant versions, but the rules in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/beddari/1472018) should be still quite close. You can probably see the commands for your version in /var/log/auth.log.

Hopefully a future Vagrant version will extract all this to a bundled script so you only need to add sudo permissions to that.